# Remove permission to User inherited from Group - Django

Tags: django, authentication, django-admin

I have a Group (let's say Operators) wich has permissions to some models, and I have a few Users who belong to that Group and inherited their permissions. Until here it's ok.

But now I want to remove the access of an User from Operators (let's say John) to one of those models that originally had permission.
Can I do this? How?

Create another Group it's not an option for me.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 5):

There aren't negative permissions in Django (fortunately, because they tend to be very unpleasant to reason about). You can't remove a permission from a user when that permission is granted to a group they're a member of, without either:

1. Removing the permission from the group, or
2. Removing the user from the group.